# Meta-analysis of studies with one group against a set baseline

Tags: meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis of single-group studies that result in proportions/percentages of correct categorisations of someone's gender. The goal is to see whether these studies correctly guess someone's gender above chance (50%).

As they are single groups, can I conduct a meta-analysis by adding a 'control group' to each study that has the same total sample as the study group with the baseline result of 50%? Or is there a more sophisticated way of conducting a meta-analysis of these single-group studies?

Comment: You say you want to see if they "correctly guess", are you trying to assess the classification performance of a fitted model? What were the studies? Do you have the actual data from the studies or just summary statistics?

Comment: Perhaps an example of a study will help clarify things. Participants were involved in computer mediated communication where they either posed as someone from the same gender (male posing as male/female posing as female) or the opposite gender (male posing as female/female posing as male). At the end of the conversation, participants were asked whether the other person is male or female. So I have percentages of the number of right guesses at the end of the conversation as well as the sample size.

Comment: I see no reason for making up data and pretending as if you had two groups in each study. You can just meta-analyze the percentages, or rather, the proportions directly.

Comment: Ah yes, meta-analysis of proportions, that is what I was looking for. Thank you for getting me on the right track Wolfgang.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a number of answers on this site which may be helpful

[Using variance from a Jeffreys prior in a Prevalence meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121990/using-variance-from-a-jeffreys-prior-in-a-prevalence-meta-analysis)

[Methods reference for meta-analysis of observational prevalence studies](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171669/methods-reference-for-meta-analysis-of-observational-prevalence-studies?rq=1)

and if you are using R @Wolfgang has a worked example on his website [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:miller1978)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. (I up-voted it but as my reputation does not (yet) exceed 15, it doesn't do anything.)